# ejabberd - mnesia table record definition : " ::binary() "

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I'm trying to understand the meaning and purpose of **::binary()** that exist in record definition but don't really understand it. Appreciate if anyone can help me to understand this.

Example : [mod_offline.hrl](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/3c2cd91fb1386c094a4b0deb92bc28225d80454e/include/mod_offline.hrl)

Comment: You mean typespecs (http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a type declaration.  This is described in the ["Type Information in Record Declarations" section](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html#id79711).

The meaning is that the value of that record field is supposed to be a binary.  Since Erlang is a weakly typed language, the compiler doesn't care about this, but there is a static type checker called [Dialyzer](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html), that tries to find places in the code that puts something other than a binary in that field, or expects the field to hold something other than a binary.

For a gentle introduction to type specs and Dialyzer, see [the Type Specifications and Erlang chapter of Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/dialyzer).